# Is there a way how to automatically force plugin execution

Tags: dynamics-crm, fakexrmeasy

I want the plugins to trigger automatically. Does the FakeXrmEasy support this ?
I tried following - plugin:

```
    public class Foo : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // never breaks here
        }
    }


    public static EntityMetadata SetObjectTypeCode(EntityMetadata metadata, int value)
    {
        var property = typeof(EntityMetadata).GetProperty(nameof(metadata.ObjectTypeCode));
        property.SetValue(metadata, value);
        return metadata;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new XrmFakedContext();
        context.InitializeMetadata(SetObjectTypeCode(new EntityMetadata
        {
            LogicalName = "account",
        }, 1));

        context.RegisterPluginStep<Foo>("Create", primaryEntityTypeCode: 1);
        context.GetOrganizationService().Create(new Entity("account", Guid.NewGuid()));
    }
```

But the plugin is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the framework [internally](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/5531248d7e9dc2a112b17735e0bf5939e974d342/FakeXrmEasy.Shared/XrmFakedContext.Pipeline.cs#L206) use the `EntityTypeCode` field of the entity to get the registered plugins.

This field is not part of the `Entity` base class but is present on the early bound classes generated by crmsvcutil.

Also, the `UsePipelineSimulation` property of the `XrmFakedContext` instance is false by default so no plugin would run, you have to set it to `true`.

Comment: I see - so the framework is making strong assumption of everyone using the crmsvcutil tool. That doesn't seem like a wise design choice - using LogicalName of entity would be more closer to how platform really works.

Comment: Actually the CRM does [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/sdkmessagefilter#BKMK_PrimaryObjectTypeCode) this type code to filter skdmessages. I think the missing link here is that when the type code is not provided, the testing framework does not search into metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested the final snippet looks like:

```cs
var context = new XrmFakedContext { UsePipelineSimulation = true };
context.RegisterPluginStep<Foo, Account>("Create", ProcessingStepStage.Postoperation);
var organizationService = context.GetOrganizationService();
organizationService.Create(new Account { LogicalName = "account" });
```

And entity metadata (all) have to be accounted for like:

```cs
[EntityLogicalNameAttribute("account")]
public class Account : Entity
{
    [AttributeLogicalName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int EntityTypeCode;

    public Account()
    {
        this.EntityTypeCode = 1;
    }
}
```

Including system-only metadata:

```cs
[EntityLogicalName("plugintype")]
public class PluginType : Entity
{
    [AttributeLogicalName("plugintypeid")]
    public Guid PluginTypeId { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("typename")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("assemblyname")]
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("major")]
    public int Major { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("minor")]
    public int Minor { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}


[EntityLogicalName("sdkmessage")]
public class SdkMessage : Entity
{
    [AttributeLogicalName("sdkmessageid")]
    public Guid SdkMessageId { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


[EntityLogicalName("sdkmessagefilter")]
public class SdkMessageFilter : Entity
{
    [AttributeLogicalName("sdkmessagefilterid")]
    public Guid SdkMessageFilterId { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("primaryobjecttypecode")]
    public int PrimaryObjectTypeCode { get; set; }
}


[EntityLogicalName("sdkmessageprocessingstep")]
public class SdkMessageProcessingStep : Entity
{
    [AttributeLogicalName("configuration")]
    public string Configuration { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("eventhandler")]
    public EntityReference EventHandler { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("sdkmessageid")]
    public EntityReference SdkMessageId { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("sdkmessagefilterid")]
    public EntityReference SdkMessageFilterId { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("filteringattributes")]
    public string FilteringAttributes { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("mode")]
    public OptionSetValue Mode { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("stage")]
    public OptionSetValue Stage { get; set; }

    [AttributeLogicalName("rank")]
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```